# error executing latex code on vs

Tags: pdftex, visual-studio-code

I recently wanted to make a .tex code in vs and I got the following:

```
Sorry, but latexmk was unsuccessful for the following reason: MiKTeX could not find the 'perl' script engine that is required to run 'latexmk'. Solution: Make sure that 'perl' is installed on your system. The log file contains the information needed to get MiKTeX working again: C:\UsersBayron\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\latexmk.log For more information, go to: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-script-engine-not-found latexmk: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.
```

I had everything working correctly, I don't know what could cause the error and how can I fix it, any help?

Comment: Have you tried the command line to run the tex file?

Comment: I have a couple suggestions: (1) Make sure that 'perl' is installed on your system. (2) Check MikTeX for updates. Those just came to me as a kind of divine inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had the strawberry perl, the only thing I did is give it in the perl built-in option called "fix errors"